# Adding controls to an ItemsControl that is placed into a UserControl when we use UserControl?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, itemscontrol, wpf-4.0

I need to make a `Usercontrol` and add it's Controls in the `Window` that i use it,so i've defined an `ItemsControl` inside it as shown below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MySystem.Controls.DropDownPanel"
      x:Name="this"   ....>
  <Grid>
    <Popup x:Name="popup" ...>
       <Grid>
           <ItemsControl ItemsControl.ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=PanelItems}">
              <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                 <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid>

                    </Grid>
                 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           </ItemsControl>
       </Grid>
     </Popup>
  </Grid>
```

And i've also created an `DependencyProprty`(PanelsItem) in the code behind:

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty PanelItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PanelItems"
        , typeof(ObservableCollection<UIElement>)
        , typeof(DropDownPanel));
    public ObservableCollection<UIElement> PanelItems
    {
        get
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<UIElement>)GetValue(PanelItemsProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PanelItemsProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

And now i wanna add controls like below:

```
<Windowx:Class="MySystem.UI.View.PeopleView"
         ...
         x:Name="this"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MySystem.Controls;assembly=MySystem.Controls">
  <Grid>
    <controls:DropDownPanel>
       <commonControls:DropDownPanel.PanelItems>
          //??How to add controls Here??
        </commonControls:DropDownPanel.PanelItems>
    </commonControls:DropDownPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

If i add Controls directly in the `PanelsItem` i'll get this error:
    {"'Collection property 'MySystem.Controls.DropDownPanel'.'PanelItems' is null'"}

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve error {"'Collection property 'MySystem.Controls.DropDownPanel'.'PanelItems' is null'"} just add default value for your dependency property. Replace:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PanelItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PanelItems"
        , typeof(ObservableCollection<UIElement>)
        , typeof(DropDownPanel));
```

to:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PanelItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PanelItems"
    , typeof(ObservableCollection<UIElement>)
    , typeof(DropDownPanel)
    , new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<UIElement>()));
```

**EDIT:**
Items are added to `PanelItems` but they aren't binded with `ItemsControl`. Instead of:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsControl.ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=PanelItems}">
```

use:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsControl.ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=PanelItems}">
```

Also, you use `Popup` control for your `ItemsControl`. So if you want see added items, you have to set a `IsOpen` property of `Popup` to true. After doing that you will be able to do this:

```
<controls:DropDownPanel DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=this}">
   <commonControls:DropDownPanel.PanelItems>
      <TextBlock Text="some text" Width="100" Height="25" />
    </commonControls:DropDownPanel.PanelItems>
</commonControls:DropDownPanel>
```

BTW `DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=this}"` isn't necessary here. You just bind `DataContext` to itself.

Comment: It doesn't show the error anymore,but nothing has been solved yet!In the fact nothing will be added to the `ItemsControl`!!

Comment: Thankyou so much,It works now,and actually it works with `ElementName` too,so i think your first answer was complete and maybe i did something wrong that i couldn't make it work!Thank you again:)